# SaltStack: Execute `systemctl --system daemon-reload` if service file was changed

Tags: systemd, saltstack

We deploy and change system service files via SaltStack.

For example, if file `/etc/systemd/system/superfoo.service` gets changed, then systemd emits this warning:

```
Warning: Unit file of superfoo.service changed on disk, 
         'systemctl --system daemon-reload' recommended.
```

How to automate this with salt-stack?

Comment: Please leave a comment if you think this question needs a down-vote: Why do you think so?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it. I hate it when it happens. Upvoted to restore balance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to provide more complete solution although @MaksaSila did answer first.

You just need a cmd.run that'll handle file change, I'm using similar approach:

```
# sample.sls

systemd-reload:
  cmd.run:
   - name: systemctl --system daemon-reload
   - onchanges:  
     - file: superbar.service

superbar.service:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/systemd/system/superbar.service

superfoo.service:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/systemd/system/superfoo.service
    - onchanges_in:
       - cmd: systemd-reload
```

The latter approach will allow you to split the systemd part and the service part into different SLS files (don't forget to include systemd for every sls file you do `onchanges_in` in).

See [this manual page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) to get more details on the state relations and dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

@jollyroger's answer is good for version < 0.15.0

Starting from 0.15.0, we can make use of `systemd_service.systemctl_reload`:
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.systemd_service.html#salt.modules.systemd_service.systemctl_reload

```
superbar.service
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/systemd/system/superbar.service
  module.run: 
    - name: service.systemctl_reload
    - onchanges:
      - file: /etc/systemd/system/superbar.service
```

I believe this greatly simplifies the code.

[Edit]
The directive "systemctl_reload" might look like `systemctl reload`, but it executes `systemctl --system daemon-reload` underneath.
https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/9bbbd3629418b2b086360f5b303323ec55ca0315/salt/modules/systemd_service.py#L377-L399

Saltstack doc also clearly states that it

> "Reloads systemctl, an action needed whenever unit files are updated."

Comment: Looks good. Thank you. But if "systemctl_reload" does "daemon-reload", why did the salt devs not name the function like this?

Comment: I don't know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. When I first looked at it, the name confused me too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest after coping this file to run this in your state:

```
update-systemd:
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl --system daemon-reload
```

Comment: This always does daemon-reload. This is not what I want. I want it only to get executed if necessary.